# Monitoração de pastas no Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

Estou precisando de uma ajuda.
Preciso montar um *shell script* que fique monitorando 4 pastas onde cada uma recebe um arquivo com *template* diferente da outra.

Preciso que quando chegue o arquivo um e-mail seja enviado para mim. Sou novo em *shell* e não encontrei nada na net.

Sugestões?

Comment: Você pode usar o [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) para monitorar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como @ qmechanik muito sabiamente sugeriu, as `inotify-utils` são um excelente
ponto de partida para esta situação. Permitem que programas sejam activados quando o ficheiro / directoria muda.

Abaixo seguem dois esqueletos de programa (um em perl outro em bash) onde podes facilmente enxertar as tuas experiências...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 use Linux::Inotify2;

 my $inotify = new Linux::Inotify2 or die "unable to inotify: $!";

 $inotify->watch ("Dir", IN_MODIFY, ## or in_{acess,create,open, etc...}
   sub { my $e = shift;
     my $name = $e->fullname;
     ## whatever 
     print "$name was modified\n" if $e->IN_MODIFY;
  });

 1 while $inotify->poll;
```

Ou usando apenas shell \cite{https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193392/96276}:

```
while inotifywait -qqe modify "$DIRECTORY"
do
    process_the_directory "$DIRECTORY"
done
```

Ver também:

```
apt-get install inotify-tools          ## instala em debian (para o esqueleto 2
cpan  Linux::Inotify2                  ## instala módulo me perl (esqueleto 1)
man inotifywait  inotifywatch Linux::Inotify2
```